# How to prevent UnitOfWork from saving changes in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a get method in which I do some filtering on some array properties of the object I want to return:

```
    public async Task<WorkflowStepDto> GetCurrentWorkflowStep(string entity, string status, string clientId = null)
    {
        var workflowStep = await _workflowStepRepository.GetAll().Include("WorkflowEntity")
                .Include("WorkflowStepActions").Include("WorkflowStepConfigurations")
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Name == status && s.WorkflowEntity.Name == entity);


       var workflowRoles = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "workflowRole").Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
       workflowStep.WorkflowStepActions =
                workflowStep.WorkflowStepActions
                    .Where(s => (workflowRoles.Contains(s.WorkflowRole) ||
                                 (workflowRoles.Length == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.WorkflowRole)) ||
                                 s.WorkflowRole == "*")).OrderBy(a => a.Priority).ToList();
       workflowStep.WorkflowStepConfigurations = workflowStep.WorkflowStepConfigurations
                .Where(c => workflowRoles.Contains(c.WorkflowStepRoleId) ||
                            (workflowRoles.Length == 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.WorkflowStepRoleId)))
                .OrderBy(c => c.Priority).Take(1).ToList();

        return workflowStep.MapTo<WorkflowStepDto>();
    }
```

For example property `WorkflowStepActions` needs to be filtered out to show only the actions the user has access to, and the same goes for `WorkflowStepConfigurations`.

The problem is the `UnitOfWork` pattern. Even though this is a `GET` method and I don't want to save any data, at the end of the method the UnitOfWork saves the changes to the database, deleting the `WorkflowStepActions` that have been filtered out in the current call.

I tried disabling the UnitOfWork alltogether using `[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled=false)]`, but then I get an error saying that the repository cannot be accessed because it has been disposed.

Is there any way to `AcceptChanges` to a UnitOfWork, or to make it stop saving changes automatically?

Comment: try Configuration.UnitOfWork.Scope = TransactionScopeOption.Suppress;

Comment: A poor man's solution might be to throw `AsNoTracking` on there if you want your own private copies of the entities to mutate.

Answer (score 2):

It's important where you use this method (in appservice, domainservice, custom class etc..)

Assuming you use it in a domain service

You have to add [UnitOfWork] attribute to method and make method virtual.

```
        [UnitOfWork] 
        public virtual async Task<WorkflowStepDto> GetCurrentWorkflowStep(string entity, string status, string clientId = null)
        {

        }
```

And if you want to save changes manually in async way. You can use the code below in any application service.

```
 await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

If you want to start a new unit of work, you can use this

```
//inject IUnitOfWorkManager to your class in constructor method.
private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;


public async Task<WorkflowStepDto> GetCurrentWorkflowStep(...)
{
    using (var uow = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        //You can save changes in any step of code to get some new inserted record's id... This is not required if you don't have such insertions.
        await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync();

        //You have to apply Complete method in the end.
        await uow.CompleteAsync();
    }
}
```

To get further information read the docs -> https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Unit-Of-Work

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround, but at this case `GetCurrentWorkflowStep` should be standalone, i.e. not implicitly called by your another code:

```
public IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager {get; set;}

[UnitOfWork(IsDisabled = true)]
public async Task<WorkflowStepDto> GetCurrentWorkflowStep(...)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
    {
        //your code....
    }
}
```